# Run an escript using TLS distribution

Tags: erlang

I have been unable to make TLS distribution work when providing arguments for the vm via the %! line in the escript.

```
cat test.es
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! +P 256000 -env ERL_MAX_ETS_TABLES 256000 -env ERL_CRASH_DUMP /dev/null -env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 0 -env ERL_MAX_PORTS 65536 +A 64 +K true +W w -smp auto -boot /tmp/start_clean -proto_dist inet_tls -ssl_dist_opt server_certfile "/var/lib/cinched/cert.pem" server_cacertfile "/var/lib/cinched/cacert.pem" client_certfile "/var/lib/cinched/cert.pem" client_cacertfile "/var/lib/cinched/cacert.pem" server_keyfile "/var/lib/cinched/key.pem" client_keyfile "/var/lib/cinched/key.pem" -name test@192.168.101.1

main(_) ->
        io:format("Ping: ~p~n",[net_adm:ping('cinched@192.168.101.1')]).


[root@dev1 ~]# ./test.es
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},"Protocol: ~tp: not supported~n",["inet_tls"]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.21.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,322}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.18.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,true}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,211}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[['test@192.168.101.1',longnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,164}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,15},{23,36,42}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

The boot file it's pointing to doesn't seem to be taken into account. I've tried other variations (trying to start the dependant apps via the -s switch), however nothing seems to work so far.

The boot file:

```
{release,{"start_clean",[]},
         {erts,"6.4"},
         [{kernel,"3.2"},
          {stdlib,"2.4"},
          {sasl,"2.4.1"},
          {crypto,"3.5"},
          {asn1,"3.0.4"},
          {public_key,"0.23"},
          {ssl,"6.0"}
          ]}.
```

Comment: Did you add `ssl` application in the boot script? Also it could be helpful to post your boot script here.

Comment: Added the boot file to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang [ssl distribution](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html) needs a started `ssl` application which should be included into a [boot script](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/script.html) and is passed to emulator with `-boot` flag. But It seems that [escript](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) doesn't pass the `-boot` flag based on this example:

**release file**:

```
{release,
 {"foo_rel", "0.1"},
 {erts, "6.4"},
 [{kernel, "3.2"},
  {stdlib, "2.4"},
  {crypto, "3.5"},
  {asn1, "3.0.4"},
  {public_key, "0.23"},
  {ssl, "6.0"}]
}.
```

**escript source**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -sname foo -boot /path/to/foo
main(_) ->
    io:format("~p~n", [application:which_applications()]).
```

**escript result**:

```
[{stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.4"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.2"}]
```

But booting the `foo` release with `erl` does start all the defined applications in boot file in a way that confirms the boot file is correct:

```
$ erl -boot /path/to/foo
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [...]
1> application:which_applications().
[{ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","6.0"},
 {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.23"},
 {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 3.0.4","3.0.4"},
 {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.5"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.4"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.2"}]
```

Although I don't know why escript doesn't pass boot script to emulator, it is obvious that using boot file escript doesn't start `ssl` application, so the ssl distribution mode cannot be started.

Comment: You've restated my question, but you are correct. The escript does not appear to take into account the boot settings, nor is there a way to get the node bootup to start up applications before the init phase, which is where I'm guessing these things need to be initialized.